# Overwriting node references when cycling through a vector with nodes (C++)

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm currently solving old exam questions for school and ran into trouble with handling references and pointers. The task is to determine if any number 'n' is divisible by 7 using a graph, nodes and different arcs.

[Graph to determining divisibility of number 'n' by 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OY3hm.png)

In the task I was given a node structure:

```
struct Node {
    int value;
    Node * grey_line;
    Node * red_line;
    };
```

I was also given a template code for a class 'Mod7' which I have written code in:

```
class Mod7 {
public:
Mod7() {
    // Create the graph here
    for (int i {}; i<7; i++) {
        nodes.push_back(Node{i});
        }
    }

    int remainder(string number) {
        // change this member function to make the test pass
        //The n_vector contains 2, 3 and 4.//
        vector<int> n_vector = string_to_vector_int(number);

        Node * current_node {&nodes.at(0)};
        int counter{};
        for (int steps : n_vector) {
            do { //step along the grey line//
                cout << "no Segmentation fault up to this point" << endl;
                current_node = current_node -> grey_line;
                cout << "Segmentation fault occurs here on the 2nd iteration of the while loop" << endl;
                steps--;
            } while (steps < 1);
            counter++;
            //Don't follow the red line if this was the last digit in v//
            if (counter == n_vector.size()) {
                return current_node -> value;
            }

            //step along the red line//
            current_node = current_node -> red_line;
        }
        return current_node -> value;
    }

    // Insert your help functions here
    void set_arcs() {
        //set grey lines//
        for (int i{}; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
            nodes.at(i).grey_line = &nodes.at( (i + 1) % 7);
        }
        //set red lines//
        nodes.at(0).red_line = &nodes.at(0);
        nodes.at(1).red_line = &nodes.at(3);
        nodes.at(2).red_line = &nodes.at(6);
        nodes.at(3).red_line = &nodes.at(2);
        nodes.at(4).red_line = &nodes.at(5);
        nodes.at(5).red_line = &nodes.at(1);
        nodes.at(6).red_line = &nodes.at(4);
        }

    vector<Node> get_node_vector() {
        return nodes;
    }

    private:

    // Insert extra data members if needed
    vector<Node> nodes{};
    };
```

The Main function looks like this:

```
int main() {
    string test1{"243"};

    Mod7 modder{};
    //A print-out I made just to make sure I created the nodes okay//
    for (Node n : modder.get_node_vector()) {
        cout << n.value << " <- Node" << endl;
    }
    
    // The examiner's required testing//
    if (modder.remainder("243") == 5) {
        cout << "Correct" << endl;
    }

    if (modder.remainder("11111111111111111111111111111") == 2) {
        cout << "Correct" << endl;
    }
}
```

**The issues** i have is I keep getting **Segmentation fault** which *I think* is due to the fact that I'm assigning new values to the current nodes' arcs. I don't know really how to continue from here, and I would greatly appreciate any help.

I don't know if the output is particularly giving, but I'll include it too:

```
> $ ./a.out
>     0 <- Node
>     1 <- Node
>     2 <- Node
>     3 <- Node
>     4 <- Node
>     5 <- Node
>     6 <- Node
>     no Segmentation fault up to this point
>     Segmentation fault occurs here on the 2nd iteration of the while loop
>     Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**UPDATE:** I just now noticed that the member function 'set_arcs()' was never called. I added a call to it after the for-loop in the class' constructor.

```
Mod7() {
    // Create the graph here
    for (int i {}; i<7; i++) {
        nodes.push_back(Node{i});
    }
    set_arcs();
}
```

Now the program get stuck in the while-loop. So I guess I'm still having issues with overwriting pointers.

Comment: `std::vector<Node> get_node_vector()` is suspicious as you return a copy of the vector (which internally point on the original vector), return by reference instead. (and method and returned reference should probably be `const`).

Comment: @Jarod42 `std::vector<Node> get_node_vector()` is only used to print the nodes' values in main. Is returning a constant reference overall a better practice? (given that you don't have to change the variables inside the vector)

Comment: `do { /*..*/--steps; } while (steps < 1);`. Your condition is strange. Did you mean `steps > 0`?

Comment: `const std::vector<Node>& get_node_vector() const` would be better (avoid extra copies). In the same ways: `for (const Node& n : modder.get_node_vector())`

Comment: Your solution on the while-loop solved the issue. Good tip on the const and reference.